# Refresh Javascript and retrieved PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After searching for several hours both in this Forum and on the Internet, I finally decided post my Problem...
I would like to update a circular progress bar using ajax but I am new to this topic and didn't succeed in transferring different solutions to my Problem.
Here is the Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#circle').circleProgress({
       value: 0.75,
       size: 150,
       fill: {
       gradient: ["red", "orange"]
       }
       });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       <?php include "itemCount2.php"; ?> 
       $('#circle').circleProgress('value', <?php echo $count ?>);
</script>
```

The second script updates my progress bar using the PHP variable $count. The database content is changing dynamically. This version is working fine. Now I'd like to execute this script every few seconds, automatically updating the progress.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Advice bro. Learn Ajax to manipulate server side from client side :)

Answer (score 0):

progrss.php

```
   $progress['progress']=(int)getProgress(); // it should return data from database i men percentage 
    echo json_encode($progress);
```

Then in your html add the following code. Hope jquery library already added.

```
$(function() {
var nre = setInterval(checkit, 5000);
function checkit(){
$.ajax({
url: 'http://yoursite/progress.php',
dataType: 'json',
cache: true,
timeout: 300000,
success: function(data) {


$.each(data, function(i,datas){
if(datas.progress<100)
{
// Write your code for circle. 
}
else
{

$('#output').html("complete. "+datas.comment);
clearInterval(nre);
}

});

},
error: function(){
$('#output ul').append('<li>Error');
}
});

}
});
```